# Visual Studio WebDeploy publish bundles newer version of dll than referenced in my solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, webdeploy, assembly-binding-redirect

I have the strange situation that my webdeploy publish process detects a newer version of a 3rd party nuget dll from my packages directory than is ever used in the solution code, and includes that in the zip bundle. This then fails when deployed to a QA server due to dll version not matching the expected version as defined in the project references.

I made a hotfix branch from **master** branch for a project that compiled and worked for me fine locally, but when I published it into a webdeploy zip file and provided it to our ops team, on our QA server, we got the infamous:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi, Version=4.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=984cb50dea722e99' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference
```

Investigations show that SimpleInjector dll version **4.0.8** is being included in the package, even though it is NEVER referenced in my solution (a look at NuGet package manager shows that the solution has no references to 4.0.8), and I have no no idea why or how this is happening??

My hotfix branch webconfig includes an automatically added a version redirect like:

```
<dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="SimpleInjector" publicKeyToken="984cb50dea722e99" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.7.0" newVersion="4.0.7.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Interestingly, in a more recent feature branch I HAD updated several libraries in the solution, SimpleInjector being one of them, so it seems that during webdeploy publish, Visual Studio is bundling up the **newest** version of the dll that it can find in my **/packages** directory, and ignoring the fact that v4.0.8 is never actually used in the hotfix branch code.

Can anyone tell me how this is possible, and how I can avoid this in future? I am tempted to try disabling the automatic version redirects, but have no experience in using that functionality so am not sure what the knock-on effects might be.